# What is the difference between select() and selectAll()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What is the difference between select() and selectAll()?

Why doesn't the second one append a p tag?

```
divSelection = d3.select('#div-vis').selectAll('p').data(['dummy']).enter().append('p');

divSelection = d3.select('#div-vis').select('p').data(['dummy']).enter().append('p');
```

Answer (score 18):

From [Nested Selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/):

> Nesting selections has another subtle yet critical side-effect: it sets the parent node for each group. The parent node is a hidden property on selections that determines where to append entering elements. … There is an important difference between select and selectAll: select preserves the existing grouping, whereas selectAll creates a new grouping. Calling select thus preserves the data, index and even the parent node of the original selection!

When you say `d3.select("#vis")`, the parent node of the selection is still the document element. When you then say `selectAll("p")`, you define the parent node as the previously-selected #vis element, because selectAll is a nesting operator. That only happens with selectAll and not select.

Answer (score 3):

In this HTML document:

```
<html>
<body>

  <div id="viz">
  </div>

<body>
</html>
```

Applying this code:

```
var viz = d3.select('#viz').selectAll('p').data([0])
  .enter().append('p');
```

Gives this result:

```
<html>
<body>

  <div id="viz">
    <p></p>
  </div>

<body>
</html>
```

This is because `selectAll()` defines a parent element based on the preceding `select` method, which is `select('#viz')`. In that way:

```
console.log(viz[0].parentNode) // <div id="viz">
```

Whereas if you execute the following code in the first HTML document:

```
var viz = d3.select('#viz').select('p').data([0])
  .enter().append('p');
```

It gives you this result:

```
<html>
<body>

  <div id="viz">
  </div>

<body>
<p></p> <!-- your p element is appended to <html> as its parent element
</html>
```

Since a `selectAll()` is required to redefine your selection's parent element, the parent element of your selection is still `<html>` which is set by default. If we log the selection's parent node:

```
console.log(viz[0].parentNode) // <html>
```

Remember that [selections are arrays (groups) of arrays of elements](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#group). Writing `viz[0]` gets the first group of elements, not the first element of your selection. To obtain the first element you should write:

```
console.log(viz[0][0].parentNode)
```

Which will give you the parent element of that specific element in the DOM tree, not in your d3 selection group.