# did nested selections in d3 change since the tutorial?

Tags: d3.js

Another thread on this topic says that the only reply that I can make must be an answer. SO, here is another thread on this topic to ask a clarifying question.

This tutorial:

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

says that the parent node of d3.select("tbody td") is html. What I get is the parent node is tr. Or, d3.select("tbody td")[0][0].parentNode is tr.

In another thread on this subject:

[Please help me understand the difference between the select() and selectAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027017/please-help-me-understand-the-difference-between-the-select-and-selectall?rq=1)

Mr. Bostock says that the parent node of select("#something").selectAll("td") is the node with id #something. What I get is the parent node is tr.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion is because of overloaded terminology.  D3 selections are 2-dimensional arrays with the first level containing "parent nodes" and second level containing "child nodes".  Another term I see used instead of parent sometimes is "group".

What you're looking at with `d3.select("tbody td")[0][0].parentNode` is the physical parent node in the DOM tree.

Selections maintain their own grouping (or parent/child) structure depending on how you chain the `select/selectAll` calls.  The children can actually be any combination of the parent nodes' descendants in the actual DOM.

Comment: That answers my question. I am still confused though. So, the parentNode property that the tutorial refers to is on the group: d3.select("tbody td")[0].parentNode. I am still not getting the significance of this.

Comment: Arghhh... Pressing enter submits the comment.... But, I am not allowed to type enough characters to make a coherent statement here anyway. Essentially, your answer plus reading the selection tutorial makes me unconfused about this topic. I was actually reading the nesting tutorial in order to understand the selection tutorial.

Comment: I think it's just a slightly confusing use of the label "parentNode" in the diagrams in the article.  It's easily confused with the property name on DOM node but I think it is just meant as a label. If you read it as "parent" instead it makes more sense.